# Clojure - how to count specific words in a string

Tags: clojure, count, words

```
(def string "this is an example string. forever and always and and")
```

can somebody help me? I coding in Clojure, and I have been trying to count how many times the word 'and' appears in the string.

any help is much appreciated

Comment: you could have added, what you tried, so it does not look totally like homework, that needs to be done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do it is to use regular expressions and [`re-seq` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-seq). Here is a "naive" example:

```
(count (re-seq #"and" string))
```

And here is the same code, written with [treading macro `->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E):

```
(->> string
     (re-seq #"and")
     count)
```

It will count all appearances of sub-string `"and"` in your `string`. It means that words like p**and**a will be counted too. But we could count only for `and` words by adding some restrictions to the regular expression (using a ["word boundary" metacharacter `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)):

```
(->> string
     (re-seq #"\band\b")
     count)
```

This version will ensure that `"and"` sub-string is surrounded by non-letter characters.

And if you want case-insensitive search (to include `"And"`):

```
(->> string
     (re-seq #"(?i)\band\b")
     count)
```

Alternative solution is to use [`split` function from `clojure.string` namespace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split):

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])

(->> (s/split string #"\W+") ; split string on non-letter characters
     (map s/lower-case) ; for case-insensitive search
     (filter (partial = "and"))
     count)
```

Comment: I think an simpler would be `\band\b`.